# Matrix multiplication for color space conversion

Tags: image-processing, color-space

In raw image processing you usually do two color space conversions using two 3x3 matrices: rgb2xyz and xyz2camera.

You could then get rgb2camera by either of these two matrix multiplications:
(1) rgb2camera = (rgb2xyz)(xyz2camera)
or:
(2) rgb2camera = (xyz2camera)(rgb2xyz)

And then get camera2rgb by inverting the rgb2camera matrix.

However, matrix multiplication is not commutative so (1) and (2) give different results. I have seen both methods in various on-line articles, but which is correct? To me, (1) looks correct (mathematically), but (2) seems to give the more correct image (visually) for the sample image I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically if you first multiply by A and then by B the correct combined matrix is BA, not AB. They go in reverse order. You can think of this as putting the vector last always so it looks logical. So the second one should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You may use both order, if you change the parameters of the *xyz2camera*. On the other hand, the variable name has also a semantic value, and your variable name seems "strange". Normally you convert from camera specific colour space to a well know colour space, so it would be much more normal to use *camera2xyz*.

Case 2 is correct if we consider semantic valid variable names:

```
rgb2camera = (xyz2camera)(rgb2xyz)
```

Let's go from right to left. We assume (from names) we are converting RGB vector (sRGB?) to RGB_camera, let's call it LMS just for fun (LMS is really just eyes reponse, not camera sensor), and you want RGB (not well specified).

```
  L                     R                              R
[ S ] =  rgb2camera * [ G ] = xyz2camera * rgb2xyz * [ G ]
  M                     B                              B
```

Your variable name implies that:

```
  X                  R
[ Y ] =  rgb2xyz * [ G ]
  Z                  B
```

so you have

```
  L                    X
[ S ] = xyz2camera * [ Y ]
  M                    Z
```

so you have the expected value:

```
  L                    R
[ S ] = rgb2camera * [ G ]
  M                    B
```

Which mean that `rgb2camera  = (xyz2camera)(rgb2xyz)` as in your second equation.

You should always interpret such multiplication from right to left. Add add a virtual vector at the end, and annotate on every step which colour space you have (which will be the input for next multiplication). So you will make less errors.

Note: photo camera sensors are usually in a form of RGB (nearly all have R, G, B filters above every photosensors). But you need to de-mosaic first, and linearize R,G,B [they are not gamma corrected, but they have own correction function].

Note: Calibration software get you a better function usually on form of LUT3D, so non-linear transformation (which you cannot get from matrices).

Comment: I agree, the terminology xyz2camera is strange, however that is the matrix that is provided in the metadata in a DNG file (ColorMatrix1 and ColorMatrix2). You really want camera2xyz.